# if I delete a product from the admin, I can't access old orders anymore

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, inventory

I am running magento 2.1. and recently I realized that if I delete a product from the admin, I can't access old orders anymore...

Does anybody have an idea what should I do?

Comment: Are you using any extension or custom code which shows image of the product in orders or something which loads products into the order view page?

Comment: Yeap.... That's right! I am currently using this https://magecomp.com/blog/display-product-image-backend-order-detail-page-magento-2/ 

Sorry for the late answer!!!